# PHP - How to increment multiple selected columns in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `mysql` table that holds the choices of music and I want to increment the value of each field by 1 which are selected. For example in my `$new_term` variable I have about four columns but in the table I have six. How do I increment the value of four columns by 1.

So far I have tried:

```
    $new_term = "`". implode("` , `" , $terms)."`";
```

The `$new_term` variable looks like this if I echo or print it;

```
    `house`, `techno`, `trance`
```

And my `sql` query is:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myMusic (".$new_term.") VALUES ("$new_term+1")");
```

But that seems incorrect. Can you please help get the right query? Thanks.

Here is my table structure

[image]

Comment: It is not quite clear what you need, can you provide the structure of your table and some simple data?

Comment: Like I want to increment the values of those three columns by 1

Comment: So you already have a record that you want to UPDATE, not a new record to INSERT?

Comment: If there is record I want to update but if not I want to insert, but basically the update statement would be similar to `Insert` in case of  it's syntax

Comment: Take a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Still, without a glimpse at your table structure we can not really help you. Do you actually have one field per music genre in your table?

Comment: I have added a picture of my table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<?
  $a = Array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) $a[] = "`{$term}` = `{$term}`+1";
  $sql = "UPDATE `myMusic` SET ".join(', ',$a);

  echo $sql;
?>
```

This should give you

```
UPDATE `myMusic` SET `house` = `house`+1, `techno` = `techno`+1, `trance` = `trance`+1
```

And you should not use **mysql_*** function because:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information.

More at http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: Yes I want something like that but the foreach loop is showing an error

Comment: Yes, see now, sorry about that.

Comment: Is `house` a row or column? That is why I said that you post your table structure and sample data. Please do that.

Comment: I have inserted the table structure already and house is a column

Comment: Oh I see, sorry about that, what do you mean that the `house`=`house`+1 is not working, it is a column, what should it do?

Comment: By default house is 0 so If I want to insert 1 to house, How should I do that? Like if I do `insert into myMusic (house) values (house+1)` it wouldn't work

Comment: You cannot `insert 1 into house`, you can only create new row with house = 1. MySQL operations are row based, so you need to update either the specific row or all rows. I suspect that you do not need house as a column at all.

Comment: Oh okay I got you now, Thanks for your help